# Android test suite using robolectric?

Tags: java, android, junit, robolectric, android-testing

I'm trying to search for an example of how to run a tests suite for test classes that use Robolectric, for example I have this class:

```
@Config(sdk = 16, manifest = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class RestaurantModelTest {

    //setUp code here...

    @Test
    public void testFindByLocation() throws Exception {
         //test code here
    }

}
```

All unit test and assertions of class `RestaurantModelTest` are passing, but I also have another class lets call it `XModelTest` (in which all assertions and unit test are passing.

## My problem

I don't find any tutorial/example of how to use a test **suite** using robolectric.

Should this be done in the same package where my RestaurantModelTest and XModelTest are? If not where?

Also I tried doing this with TestSuite from JUnit but many questions arise should the class with my TestSuite extend extends TestSuite super class?

If someone can give me a short example using my `RestaurantModelTest`and `XModelTest`classes it would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe, I've also partially covered this question answering your second question - [Can't run android test suite: Exception in thread “main”](http://java.lang.ClassNotFoundExceptionhttps://stackoverflow.com/a/34354051/1658267)

Here's how to write a suite with Robolectric:
Let's say we have 2 model classes.

`CartModel.java`

```
public class CartModel {
    public float totalAmount;
    public int products;

    public void addToCart(float productPrice) {
        products++;
        totalAmount += productPrice;
    }
}
```

and `RestaurantModel.java`

```
public class RestaurantModel {    
    public int staff;

    public void hire(int numberOfHires) {
        staff += numberOfHires;
    }
}
```

Let's write some dummy tests for them:

`CartModelTest.java`

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk=21)
public class CartModelTest {

    @Test
    public void addToCart() throws Exception {
        CartModel cartModel = new CartModel();
        assertEquals(0, cartModel.totalAmount, 0);
        assertEquals(0, cartModel.products);
        cartModel.addToCart(10.2f);
        assertEquals(10.2f, cartModel.totalAmount, 0);
        assertEquals(1, cartModel.products);
    }
}
```

`RestaurantModelTest.java`

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk=21)
public class RestaurantModelTest {

    @Test
    public void hire() throws Exception {
        RestaurantModel restaurantModel = new RestaurantModel();
        assertEquals(0, restaurantModel.staff);
        restaurantModel.hire(1);
        assertEquals(1, restaurantModel.staff);
    }
}
```

And now last step - to group them together into one `ModelsTestSuite.java`:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
        RestaurantModelTest.class,
        CartModelTest.class
})
public class ModelsTestSuite {}
```

To run - just right-click in `ModelsTestSuite` and click "Run ModelsTestSuite". That's it!

**NB!** In Android Studio 2.0 3b, you have to disable instant run (Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run -> Enable Instant Run - uncheck) in order to run Robolectric tests (to avoid `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not find a class for package: <package name> and class name: com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication`).

I hope, it helps

Comment: thanks so much you past answer answered my problem perfectly!!! thanks for answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34317022/cant-run-android-test-suite-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-classnotfound?noredirect=1#comment56376122_34317022