# Can't run android test suite: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, junit, robolectric, android-testing

I have 2 test classes that I need to run on a test suite one is `RestaurantModelTest`the other is `CartModelTest.class`:

```
@Config(sdk = 16, manifest = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class RestaurantModelTest {

    //setUp code here...

    @Test
    public void testFindByLocation() throws Exception {
         //test code here
    }

}
```

So I followed some tutorials online and they specify to create a TestSuite class like this with my 2 classes to be tested:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
        RestaurantModelTest.class,
        CartModelTest.class
})
public class ModelsTestSuite {

}
```

And then I must create a TestSuiteRunner class:

```
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

public class TestSuiteRunner {


    public static void main(String[] args){
        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(ModelsTestSuite.class);
        for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()){
            System.out.println(failure.toString());
        }
        System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());

    }
}
```

I'm using android studio and when I hate right-click > Run TestSuiteRunner...main() I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:`

any help really appreciated!

Comment: I think you are missing some jar files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do to run all the tests in suite - is to:

1. Right-click in `ModelsTestSuite`
2. Click "Run ModelsTestSuite"

That's it, all tests in the suite will be executed. You don't really need `TestSuiteRunner` class for that:

[image]

**NB!** While solving this problem, I found another bizarre one: unless I **disabled instant run** (Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run -> Enable Instant Run - uncheck) in Android Studio 2.0, all my Robolectric tests were failing with `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`. jFYI.

The reason you get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` is incompatibility of plain java projects and Android projects. You can read more here: [Can Android Studio be used to run standard Java projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626810/can-android-studio-be-used-to-run-standard-java-projects)

So, theoretically, to have `TestSuiteRunner` in this form, you could move it to separate Java library module and link Android app's module as a dependency for this Java lib. Unfortunately, you'd get this warning:

> Warning:Ignoring dependency of module 'app' on module 'lib'. Java modules cannot depend on Android modules

i.e. it's not gonna work this way.

I hope, it helps.

Comment: omg that was it it was soooo simple!!!! yet trying to find documentation was kinda diffucult you are the best thanks!!!!!, how did you know how to do it? is there any documentation online I'm missing?

Comment: @JesSys my pleasure! Actually, I haven't seen documentation regarding it: this approach just seemed to be consistent with rest of Android test framework and apparently I spent a bit too much time digging into Android's tests :-) . So I just tried - and luckily it worked.